# HTML Page being cleared after run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I am practicing using jQuery with my html. I have a form that is asking questions about your car. The problem is everything works but after  it does the form reset it deletes everything that was just added.

I debugged the program and it is doing exactly what I want but once it stops executing "writeHtml" everything it just did gets cleared.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Sabio Practice </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                function writeHtml(){           
                    var model = $("#Model").val();
                    var make = $("#Make").val();
                    var year = $("#Year").val();
                    var vin = $("#VIN").val();

                    $("#pp").html("<ul>")
                    $("#pp").html("<li>Make: " + make + "</li>" +
                                "<br/><li>Model: " + model + "</li>" +
                                "<br/><li>Year: " + year + "</li>" +
                                "<br/><li>VIN: " + vin + "</li>");
                    $("#pp").html("</ul>")
                }

                console.log("got here");

                $("#Register").click(function(){

                    writeHtml();
                    $("#myForm")[0].reset();                
                });

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form id = "myForm" method = "get">         
                <input id = "Model" placeholder = "Model"><br>
                <input id = "Make" placeholder = "Make"><br>
                <input id = "Year" type = "number" placeholder = "Year"><br>
                <input id = "VIN" placeholder = "VIN"><br>

                <button id = "Register" name = "Register"> Register</button>
                <button id = "Cancel" name = "Cancel">Cancel</button>
            </form>
            <p id = "pp">

            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I just want the edits made to the DOM to be permanent.

Comment: So you are resetting a form and don't want it cleared?

Comment: no sir the ul should be below the form but everything I add with regards to the ul disappears once "writeHtml" leaves scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override with `html()` your content, better is to use `append()`

```
  $("#pp").append("<ul>")
                $("#pp").append("<li>Make: " + make + "</li>" +
                            "<br/><li>Model: " + model + "</li>" +
                            "<br/><li>Year: " + year + "</li>" +
                            "<br/><li>VIN: " + vin + "</li>");
                $("#pp").append("</ul>")
```

And set the type of your button to `button`. Otherwise the form is submitted.

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

Comment: This works but the problem is even with this it shows for a split second and then disappears again

Comment: Set button type to `<button type="button"></button>`.

Comment: Combine this answer and Eponyme Web's answer if you are using Chrome

Comment: Thank this worked, and it made me do a little research too. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You should also prevent the default behavior, your event subscription should look like this:

```
    $("#Register").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      writeHtml();
      $("#myForm")[0].reset();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

when you don't set the type in a form, it's a submit;
so you should set the button type button;like this:

```
<button id = "Register" name = "Register" type="button"> Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had two problems. One was I was overwriting my innerhtml again after I overwrote it the first time.

The second problem was I did not specify a type for the button. The default type for button is "submit" since my form was therefore being submitted it was redirecting me to a fresh page of my page.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Sabio Practice </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                function writeHtml(){           
                    var model = $("#Model").val();
                    var make = $("#Make").val();
                    var year = $("#Year").val();
                    var vin = $("#VIN").val();
                    var htmlText = "<ul>";
                   htmlText += `<li>Make: ${make}</li>
                                <br/>
                                <li>Model: ${model}</li>
                                <br/>
                                <li>Year: ${year}</li>
                                <br/>
                                <li>VIN: ${vin}</li>`;
                  htmlText += "</ul>"
                    $("#pp").append(htmlText);
                }

                console.log("got here");

                $("#Register").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    writeHtml();
                     $("#myForm")[0].reset();                
                });

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form id = "myForm" >         
                <input id = "Model" placeholder = "Model"><br>
                <input id = "Make" placeholder = "Make"><br>
                <input id = "Year" type = "number" placeholder = "Year"><br>
                <input id = "VIN" placeholder = "VIN"><br>

                <button id = "Register" name = "Register"> Register</button>
                <button id = "Cancel" name = "Cancel">Cancel</button>
            </form>
            <p id = "pp">

            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The form gets submitted when clicked on the button. Either use e.preventDefault() or use type="button" in html.